# How to join AWS EC2 ubuntu instance to simple directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

in AWS I am trying to join `ubuntu` EC2 instance to AWS simple directory. I used steps described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/simple_ad_join_linux_instance.html) to manually join instance.

First i Connected to instance using PuTTY

In step 4 i executed the following command

`$ sudo apt-get -y install sssd realmd krb5-user samba-common packagekit adcli`

As mentioned in the article, i was presented with several pop-up configuration screens and i left the fields in these screens blank.

then i tried to join the instance to the directory with the following command.

`$ sudo realm join -U user@INTERNAL.MYCOMPANY.COM internal.mycompany.com --verbose`

*Since instance has Ubuntu 16.04, i entered the domain name portion of the username with all capital letters*

However i am getting the `No such realm found` error

[image]

I am not linux expert, infact this is the first time i am using linux. All other instances in our network are windows.

Can anyone guide me what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

found it

To configure an EC2 instance running Linux to use static DNS server entries, use a text editor such as vim to edit the file /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf and add the following line to the end of the file:

`supersede domain-name-servers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;`

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP address of a DNS server that you want the instance to use

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-static-dns-ubuntu-debian/

and then try to join using

`$ sudo realm join -U user@INTERNAL.MYCOMPANY.COM internal.mycompany.com --verbose`